# Similarity between more than two strings Java

Tags: java, string, compare, levenshtein-distance

I know there are several algorithms (Soundex Algorithm, Levenshtein distance/ Edit Distance, and Longest Common Substring)  that can be used to compare **two** strings. Is there a known way to compare **more than two** strings and eliminate ones that are the least similar based on say a Max Levenshtein distance you've set?

Example:

```
 String -> {sam, ham, jam, stackoverflow}
```

Assuming I set my Levenshtein distance to 2 the output should have only three surviving items.

```
Output -> {sam, ham, jam}
```

The implementation I have has an O(n^2) Time Complexity. Is there a better/clever way of doing this?

Method signature:

```
public String[] bestMatches (String[] s, int levenshteinDistanceMax){


}
```

Comment: I think you need to define the problem better. Are you looking for a maximal set? What is the output if your starting set is`{sam, ham, jam, stackoverflow, htackoverflow, jtackoverflow}` for a  Levenshtein distance of 2?

Comment: That is correct. I wish to return the maximal set. But in a scenario, like the one you have above, I will choose either set {sam, ham, jam} or {stackoverflow, htackoverflow, jtackoverflow} at random.